# How can i get the multiple scaled images to fit to their scaled size and move them to any position on the screen of my wish?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android.I am doing a project which contains two vertical linear layouts left linear and right linear.leftlinear contains images.those images should be dragged to rightlinear and they should be zoomed and moved to any position on the screen of users wish one by one.and for zooming, entire screen may be used(likewise for all images,so while zooming the second image, it may come on the first image even and i should have the combined images one on another for displaying).finally rightlinear should display all the images which are scaled and dragged.please help me out.My main Activity is

```
            package com.example.example;
            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.util.Random;
            import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.DragEvent;
            import android.view.MotionEvent;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
             import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
             import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
           import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
           import android.widget.Button;
           import android.widget.ImageView;
          import android.widget.LinearLayout;
          import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnTouchListener,OnDragListener{
ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4,iv5,iv6,iv7,iv8;
Button display,save;
LinearLayout leftlinear;
LinearLayout rightlinear;
private static final String LOGCAT = null;
ImageView image;
AlertDialog option;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    iv4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    iv5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    iv6=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    iv7=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    display=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    leftlinear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.leftlinear);
    rightlinear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rightlinear);
     iv1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     iv2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     iv3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     iv4.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     iv5.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     iv6.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     iv7.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv3.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv4.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv4.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv5.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv5.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv6.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv6.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv7.setOnTouchListener(this);
    iv7.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    leftlinear.setOnDragListener(this);
    rightlinear.setOnDragListener(this);        
    iv1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    display.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv1.setVisibility(0);
            iv2.setVisibility(0);
            iv3.setVisibility(0);
            iv4.setVisibility(0);
            iv5.setVisibility(0);
            iv6.setVisibility(0);
            iv7.setVisibility(0);



        }
    });
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rightlinear.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            rightlinear.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = rightlinear.getDrawingCache();
            File resultingfile;  
            try {
                File rootFile=new          File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MYBOARD");
                rootFile.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";

                resultingfile=new File(rootFile, fname);

                if (resultingfile.exists ()) resultingfile.delete (); 
                try {
                       FileOutputStream Fout = new FileOutputStream(resultingfile);
                       bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, Fout);
                       Fout.flush();
                       Fout.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
          } catch (Exception e) {
        }



        }
    });

}
   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
      view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);      
      return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
   }  
public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
      int action = dragevent.getAction();
      switch (action) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
          Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into "+layoutview.toString());
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
          Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from "+layoutview.toString());
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");           
        image=new ImageView(this);
        View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
        image.setImageBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;         
        container.addView(image);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        image.setLayoutParams(params);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX );

        image.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());            


        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
              Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
          break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
```

}

}

```
    and myTouchListener class is(I copied it from the net and made necessary changes) 

         package com.example.example;
         import android.graphics.Matrix;
         import android.graphics.PointF;
         import android.util.FloatMath;
          import android.util.Log;
         import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
          import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
           import android.widget.ImageView;
         import android.widget.LinearLayout;

        public class myTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
      private static final String TAG = "Touch" ;

    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    //These matrices will be used to move and zoom image  
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
      Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();  

// We can be in one of these 3 states  
static final int NONE = 0;  
static final int DRAG = 1;  
static final int ZOOM = 2;  
int mode = NONE;  

// Remember some things for zooming  
PointF start = new PointF();  
PointF mid = new PointF();  
float oldDist = 1f;  
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;     
      // Dump touch event to log  
      dumpEvent(event);  

      // Handle touch events here...  
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) { 

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
       savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
       start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());  
       mode = DRAG;  
       break;  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:  
       oldDist = spacing(event);  
       if (oldDist > 10f) {  
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
        midPoint(mid, event);  
        mode = ZOOM;  
       }  
       break;  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:  
       mode = NONE;  
       break;  
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
       if (mode == DRAG) {  
        // ...      
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);  


       } else if (mode == ZOOM) {  
        float newDist = spacing(event);  
        if (newDist > 10f) {  
         matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
         float scale = newDist / oldDist;  
         matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y); 
        }  
       }  
       break;  
      }  
      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; 
      // indicate event was handled  
     }  
     /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */  
     private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",  
        "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };  
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
      int action = event.getAction();  
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;  
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);  
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN  
        || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {  
       sb.append("(pid ").append(  
         action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);  
       sb.append(")");  
      }  

      sb.append("[");  
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {  
       sb.append("#").append(i);  
       sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));  
       sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));  
       sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));  
       if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())  
        sb.append(";");  
      }  
      sb.append("]");  
     }  

     /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */  
     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {  
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);  
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);  
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);  
     }  

     /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */  
     private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {  
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);  
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);  
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);  
     }  
    }
```

and my xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text="Display" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Save" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftlinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/new1"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/new2"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/new3"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/new4"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image5"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image6"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightlinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As it sounds to me, the description of your issue is difficult to understand. Maybe you could provide a quick sketch of what you want to do (a picture) ?

Comment: I want to display more images on the screen which can be made to drag  to any position on the screen and zoom.I could do only one image in that manner.I want more than one image.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand :s